# insert one column into another table having two columns (original and 1.5*original) in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying import one column from another table1 into table 2. Table 2 has two columns. one column is the original one and another one is 1.5*original.

I use two steps:

first
insert into table2
select col1
from table 1

then update table2
set col2=1.5*col2

can I do it in one step?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure:

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT col1, col1*1.5 AS col2 FROM table1
```